# Toggle buttons in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Can some on tell me if there is smething wrong with the below code as I am unable to get the buttons toggled

```
 <div class="modal-footer textAlignLeft">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"
            name="close" ng-show="!closeHidden"
            ng-click="cancel()">CLOSE</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"
            name="cancel" ng-show="closeHidden"
            ng-click="cancelUpload()">CANCEL</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary marLeft10"
            name="attachfile" id="uploadBtn"
            ng-click="attach()" ng-disabled="attachDisabled">
       {{ resource["common.attachbtn"] }}
    </button>
</div>
```

Once I click on attach button, I want the close button to disappear and the cancel button to show up. But it always shows only the close button though I see the scope variable scope.closeHidden updated to true in my code. Any hints?

Comment: please show `scope.closeHidden` value.

Comment: And also, how you set its value, in cancel() and cancelUpload() as I assume

Comment: Hi, This worked. It was a mismatch in scope variable I used.